# What does 腕が光る mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I've tried Googling for Japanese/Japanese dictionary definitions of this phrase, but can only find usages so far, which haven't helped.

More context:

"俺たち職人の腕が光る"

I think from context that the speaker is saying "so that us artisans do well / look good / show how good we are", or something in that area, but dictionaries haven't been helpful so far - hoping Japanese StackExchange can solve the riddle!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things to define in `腕が光る`:

- `腕`, which can mean skill or ability ([大辞林 sense 3](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E8%85%95))
- `光る`, which can mean to stand out as superior [in ability, etc.] ([大辞林 sense 3](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E5%85%89%E3%82%8B))

The latter is, I think, figurative in the same sense as English [shine](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/shine) ("To distinguish oneself in an activity or a field; excel").  Put the two words together with `が`, and you have a phrase meaning something like "to stand out as superior in skill or ability".

I'm basing this entirely on dictionary entries, by the way.  I think my interpretation is right (which is why I'm posting it as an answer), but if I've made a mistake, I would appreciate it if someone pointed it out :-)